# Google App engine local server not get started

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to run google app engine project on my local development server. The server gets started . But when I try to access the application , it shows me below error .Any suggestion on how to fix this issue ?

```
Nov 28, 2019 5:15:09 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Nov 28, 2019 5:15:09 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Nov 28, 2019 10:45:09 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Nov 28, 2019 10:45:11 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext disableTransportGuarantee
INFO: Ignoring <transport-guarantee> for /a/tasks/* as the SDK does not support HTTPS.  It will still be used when you upload your application.
Nov 28, 2019 10:45:11 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext disableTransportGuarantee
INFO: Ignoring <transport-guarantee> for /a/cron/* as the SDK does not support HTTPS.  It will still be used when you upload your application.
Nov 28, 2019 10:45:11 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext disableTransportGuarantee
INFO: Ignoring <transport-guarantee> for /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create as the SDK does not support HTTPS.  It will still be used when you upload your application.
2019-11-28 10:45:11.214:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp125622176-25: /
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.resetBuffer(HttpChannel.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.resetBuffer(HttpOutput.java:1080)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetForForward(Response.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:270)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:125)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text, instead copy-paste the text in your post and format it accordingly. Thx.

Comment: What runtime of App Engine are you using, according to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command), it seems that not all runtimes are available for the local server.

Comment: @DanCornilescu , Ok Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @rsalinas. Java 8 runtime is being used. From the logs, It is shown that devserver has started,but when the URL is hit , it being redirected back at some point and throws 503 service unavailable.

Comment: Do you have any handlers on your app.yaml, or are you able to share this file? that would be helpful to try and reproduce this.